# what is this "scheme don't have a registered handler" error?

Tags: node.js, handler

I am working on a node app.
i have an ejs file , where on clicking a button a get request is made to this url `localhost:3000/posts/business-economics`
but the page doesn't load up and this error is shown in the console

> Failed to launch 'localhost:3000/posts/business-economics' because the scheme does not have a registered handler.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

I encountered the same error while working with the localhost. I was trying to redirect to localhost:3000 and I got this error flashing on my console.
It turns out that it's because the **http:// is missing** from the url you're trying to load. I'm amazed to see that no one has answered this yet.

Comment: Even After adding http:// it is still there. I think error arises because the site is not an https one

Comment: mercadopago is not allowing me to add localhost as redirect URL for Oauth, I can only set that value if I take HTTP out. So the process of Authorization with oauth fails local.

Comment: This solved my Sanity.io next js preview pane if anyone else is searching

Comment: in development environment usually we have a localhost, If you miss there you can see that error (http://localhost:4000)

Answer (score 18):

you must set address protocol before url ,like:

```
returnUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + Path
```

Answer (score 7):

If url missing the protocol http or https. Another reason which I also faced. If href tag has wrong spelling of javascript

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="myfunction()">Action</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, an URL with the wrong format may end on such error.

A window.open command with the wrong format on the first parameter may throw this error too:

```js
var emptyWindow = window.open('Window title', '_blank');
// Console output: 
// Failed to launch 'Window%20title' 
// because the scheme does not have a registered handler.'
```

In the case above, the developer (me, some time ago) forgot that the first parameter must be there even when you want to open a blank page:

`var emptyWindow = window.open('', 'Window title', '_blank');`

The value is optional but not the parameter itself.

A malformated first parameter may throw this same error too.

Answer (score -9):

Sometimes, juste to to restart your app could change something or to check again the url path that you give it coud also be a mistake over there

Comment: Actually this is not a precise but a correct answer. Author had a mistake in URL path. Missing Http.