# cannot start second instance of angular app from within app

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have an Angular 11 app that consists of an app and 2 lazy loaded modules. The one module is the user ui, the second lazy loaded module is the admin ui.
Now I want to start the admin ui from within the user ui. I thought I would just open a new tab with the url like so:

```
window.open(location.host+'/index.html#/admin','_blank');
```

This will open a new tab and put the link in the navigation, but then will stop and throw the error:

> Failed to launch 'localhost:4200/index.html#/admin' because the scheme
> does not have a registered handler.

If I then reload this new window, the app will start correctly.
I have also tried:

```
this.router.navigate([]).then(window.open(url, '_blank'));
```

with the same result.

Is there a limitation to start another instance of an angular app from within an angular app?

Comment: Did you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64797802/what-is-this-scheme-dont-have-a-registered-handler-error ? It seems you are missing the scheme in the beginning of the url so its location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/#/admin'

Comment: your are certainly right.....stupid mistake of mine ;-).....thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the location.protocol in the link.....as sugested by misha130