# failed to launch the url because the scheme does not have a registered handler

Tags: html, css, web, media-queries

I am fixing the media queries on my project website.

On desktop, max-width is fine, I'm still able to access the link. But when i go to mobile max-width (420px) up to tablet max-width 1024px this is the error I saw on my console:

> Failed to launch 'intent://leakymosfet.page.link/BiosCreator#Intent;package=com.google.android.gms;action=com.google.firebase.dynamiclinks.VIEW_DYNAMIC_LINK;scheme=https;S.browser_fallback_url=https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GF9vZn2I-9SJc3n2Kfivf-471e0vAt3j/view%3Fusp%3Dsharing;end;' because the scheme does not have a registered handler.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! This is weird but most likely unrelated to Jekyll, have you seen This is weird, have you seen this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64797802/what-is-this-scheme-dont-have-a-registered-handler-error?

Comment: Also, please share some code and post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).